# Mocking super class calls in Perl (using Test::MockObject)

Tags: perl, unit-testing, inheritance

I'm using MockObjects in some of my tests and just had to test a function with a call to a SUPER class and I cannot seem to make it work. Can UNIVERSAL calls like $this->SUPER::save() not be mocked? If yes, how do you do it?

Thanks.

Edit:

Found it!

Use `fake_module` from `Test::MockObject`

So, let's say your base module it `Some::Module`, and your subroutine is making a `$this->SUPER::save` call, use

```
my $child_class_mockup = Test::MockObject->new();
$child_class_mockup->fake_module(
    'Some::Module',
    save => sub () { return 1; } 
);
```

Leaving the question open for a couple of days, to get inputs about different ways/libraries of doing this (what if, the SUPER call had a SUPER call?) before accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out the name of the object's superclass (or one of the superclasses, since Perl has multiple inheritance), and define the `save` call in the superclass's package.

For example, if you have

```
package MyClass;
use YourClass;
our @ISA = qw(YourClass);   # <-- name of superclass
...
sub foo {
    my $self = shift;
    ...
    $self->SUPER::save();    # <--- want to mock this function in the test
    ...
}

sub save {
    # MyClass version of save method
    ...
}
```

then in your test script, you would say

```
no warnings 'redefine';     # optional, suppresses warning

sub YourClass::save {
    # mock function for $yourClassObj->save, but also
    # a mock function for $myClassObj->SUPER::save
    ...
}
```